# How/where do I register the IDbPerTenantConnectionStringResolver

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Trying to run core api host.  i have this in the EntityFrameworkModule

```
    public override void PreInitialize()
{
    Configuration.MultiTenancy.IsEnabled = true;`

   // CONNECTION STRING RESOLVER
    Configuration.ReplaceService<IConnectionStringResolver, DbPerTenantConnectionStringResolver>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);

    Configuration.DefaultNameOrConnectionString = MyConsts.DefaultConnectionStringName;

    if (!SkipDbContextRegistration)
    {
        //DEFAULT
        Configuration.Modules.AbpEfCore().AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
        {
            if (options.ExistingConnection != null)
                MyContextConfigurer.Configure(options.DbContextOptions, options.ExistingConnection);
            else
                MyContextConfigurer.Configure(options.DbContextOptions, options.ConnectionString);
        });

    }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
 Mvc.ExceptionHandling.AbpExceptionFilter - Can't create component 'Ccre.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpZeroDbMigrator' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.

'Ccre.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpZeroDbMigrator' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'Abp.MultiTenancy.IDbPerTenantConnectionStringResolver' which was not registered.
```

How/where  do I register the `IDbPerTenantConnectionStringResolver`?

I have this line in the `PreInitialize` of the Migrator.MigratorModule

```
Configuration.ReplaceService<IConnectionStringResolver, DbPerTenantConnectionStringResolver>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
```

as well as in the EntityFrameworkModule

Comment: If you depend on ``AbpZeroEntityFrameworkCoreModule`` then it already registers ``DbPerTenantConnectionStringResolver`` (see https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.Zero.EntityFrameworkCore/Zero/EntityFrameworkCore/AbpZeroEntityFrameworkCoreModule.cs#L18). You don't need to register it, delete the ``ReplaceService`` line from your code. Also, notice that ``AbpZeroEntityFrameworkCoreModule`` replaces it differently.

Comment: thanks - i''ll try that - so i assume it knows it is a db/tennant  is it due to the optional connection string the tennant can have?

Comment: my problem seems to be i keep underestimating how easy this framework is t use.  i keep doing too much!  ta

Comment: @hikalkan and what if it is not depands on AbpZeroEntityFrameworkCoreModule, but AbpZeroCoreModule instead, should I register it by myself using ReplaceService?